# Modify pointer inside class

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm having a trouble manipulating a pointer inside a class.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myClass {
public:
    void modifyPointer(float *pointer);
};

void myClass::modifyPointer(float *pointer) {
    pointer = new float[3];
    pointer[0] = 0;
    pointer[1] = 1;
    pointer[2] = 2;
    cout << "Address: " << pointer << endl;
}

int main()
{
    float* pointer;
    myClass object;
    object.modifyPointer(pointer);
    cout << "Address: " << pointer << endl;
    cout << "Values: " << pointer[0] << "," << pointer[1] << "," << pointer[2]
        << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I print the pointer inside the class I get its address, but in the main program I get a 0 address and a seg fault when printing values. What am I wrong in how to modify this pointer?

Comment: It seems odd, and sometimes takes a while to get your head wrapped around it, but while the pointer effectively passes another object by reference, the pointer itself is passed by value.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't thinking the pointer as an object. Now this totally makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking the pointer by copy, so you don't see the changes in `main`. You need to take the pointer by reference, like this:

```
void myClass::modifyPointer(float * &pointer) {
   pointer = new float[3];
   // ...
}
```

You have to change the declaration of this function as well, of course.

Here's a working [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GjzZg3).

Answer (score 3):

Pointers are just like any other objects. Passing an object as an argument by value creates a copy of that object. This means the original `pointer` in `main()` remains unaffected. And since it is unaffected and not initialized, accessing an array out of bounds with `pointer[any_index]` results in [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Pass by reference instead:

```
void modifyPointer(float*& pointer)
```